# Python object to call another file function

Tags: python

Here is a simplified code of my problem. I have a class in file 'class1.py' and eventHandler gets called sometimes by another function in that class.

```
class FOO:
    def eventHandler(self, message):
        processMessage(message)
```

And I want the class to call function processMessage that is in file 'main.py'.

```
from class1 import FOO

def processMessage(message):
    processMore(message)

def processMore(message):
    print(message)

myClass = FOO()
```

How can this be done? Do I have to pass the processMessage to the object and can then it call another function that is not passed?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, let's use a simple example analogous to your situation. We have two files:

#### foo.py

```
from bar import bar


class Foo:
    def foo():
        bar()
```

#### bar.py

```
from foo import Foo


def bar():
    print('bar')


foo = Foo()
```

Indeed, when we run `python foo.py` we get `ImportError: cannot import name 'bar'`.
This is caused by circular dependency (for more info on importing go [here](http://effbot.org/zone/import-confusion.htm)). One very simple way to avoid it is to
move `from foo import Foo` to the bottom of the file:

#### bar.py 2

```
def bar():
    print('bar')


from foo import Foo
foo = Foo()
```

Now it should work.